# Using GCM for Push Notifications

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to follow a tutorial on using GCM to push notifications for my application. I have the server up and running, and the android app running. From the server, I can push a notification message, but the notification only pops up when the activity is actually running. How can I register, in my manifest I assume, to answer notifications when the app isn't up and running.

Comment: Have you considered to read the actual documentation? It's right there. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use web searches for information readily available.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was missing an adjustment to my manifest and broadcast receiver.